# Linux awk script - convert pipe delimited to fixed width

Tags: linux, awk

I am trying to convert a pipe delimited input file to a fixed width file.  Below is the input file and the expected output.  I have also included the script I am attempting.  I have tried several variations without success.  I am very new to Linux and have been trying to piece together bits and pieces of code to help me understand better, but i am failing and hoping someone will be able to assist me.

awk -v FS="|" FIELDWIDTHS="9 1 2 1 2 2 5 5 7 10 9 11" -v OFS="" '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11}' input.txt > output.txt

```
$ cat input.txt
# Input File
#
aa|bbb|cccc|ddddd|
#


 $ cat output.txt
 # Output File
 #
 aabbbccccdddddd
 #
```

Comment: "Using different vars of awk I am able to strip" ... Do you have something else to tell us?  Does `awk -F\| '{printf("%2s%3s%4s%5s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4)}' datFile` help any? Good luck.

Comment: The question makes absolutely no sense. Please completely rewrite it to be clear and provide testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: I have updated my question above with more information....sorry for the crappy original explanation

Comment: @EdMorton - i have updated the information.  sorry for the rookie mistake.  i am new to linux and wasnt thinking when i originally posted.

Comment: @shellter this worked! thank you! how do i make sure to rate you or give you props?

Comment: @DanK if that's what you want all you need is `tr -d '|'` < file`.

Comment: @EdMorton is it appropriate on this type of board to ask you for more information? what would the full line of code look like?  awk tr -d < file?

Comment: @DanK. Glad my answer helped. As this is your first Q and don't know all the rules of S.O., I would comment that when someone posts you a code snippet that you don't understand, you can go to your command line and type `man tr`, or `man ls`, or `man awk`, etc, etc. To be fair `man` pages are not tutorials, but read the top level description, try to graps some of the arguments (`-d` in this case), and then if you still have questions, read some of the other Q/A here on S.O. for that cmd. Unfortunately `tr` is also an html tag and has quite a few Qs already. So it won't always work!

Comment: . . . Finally, Learn to write clear and simple questions that 1. include small sample data sets that cover all cases that you expect to process, including 'what do I do if there are errors in the format of my data'. 2. show the required output, from that same input. 3. Show your code. 4/ Show error messages you may be getting along with any context for that error. 5. include a discussion of what you thought should work VS what is really happening. . . . .

Comment: I won't be writing up an answer. If others do, and it works for you, then be sure to 'accept' the answer so that the writer gets reputation points, and will be motiviated to write more answers. OK? ;-) And good luck.

Comment: @Dan no, awk has nothing to do with this. `tr -d '|' < file` is the full line of code. I posted an answer showing it.

Comment: @shelter i dont see where i can accept your answer, but i did see one for EdMorton so I did accept that.  Both of your responses work and i have some small code to build off of.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need awk for this and even if you did it'd have nothing to do with FIELDWIDTHS, can't imagine where you were getting any of that from. All you need is `tr`:

```
$ cat input.txt
# Input File
#
aa|bbb|cccc|ddddd|
#

$ tr -d '|' < input.txt
# Input File
#
aabbbccccddddd
#
```

To begin learning how to use shell and awk, get the books "Shell Scripting Recipes" by Chris Johnson, and "Effective Awk Programming", 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: thank you! this is perfect! Thank you for the recommendation as well.  Will be ordering that today.